# Persistent scheduling

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scheduled-tasks, akka

I'm currently in need of persistent scheduling for a web app based on play-framework and akka. I know there is actor scheduling in akka, but as far as I know, it provides no mechanism to persist jobs. So, even if pretty much everything fails, jobs have to be loaded, and executed, after a restart. The jobs are generally not going to be periodic.

What kind of system can accomplish those things, and possibly nicely integrate into the existing infrastructure (play, akka)?

Comment: Any tips on how that could be combined?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing your scheduler generates tasks. Those tasks could be considered messages sent to some executing actor, and that actor can have a durable mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a project capable of doing "timestamp based persistent scheduling for Akka":  https://github.com/odd/akkax-scheduling

Answer (score 0):

We are using Quartz, it's written in Java, but there is a good persistence mechanism which can use either RAM store or some database (we are using Mongo)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [db-scheduler](https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler/), a persistent cluster-friendly task-scheduler I am the author of. It is easily embeddable in a JVM-app, and requires only a single database-table for persistence. (Note: it is designed for small to medium workloads)

Answer (score -3):

You can try using the scheduling mechanism in Akka.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/scheduler.html

For example:

```
//Schedules a function to be executed (send the current time) to the testActor after 50ms
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds) {
   testActor ! System.currentTimeMillis
}
```

Comment: I know of this. The problem is, the default scheduler offers no persistence at all.